# Plotting Bigrams in Bar Chart with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, text-mining, tidytext

My data looks like this:

```
> str(bigrams_joined)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   71319 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ line   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ bigrams: chr  "in practice" "practice risk" "risk management" "management is"
```

I would like to plot the top 10 or 15 most frequently occurring bigrams in my dataset to a bar chart in ggplot2 and have the bars running horizontally with the labels on the y-axis.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: top 15 of what? just the top 15 or the top 15 per line?

Comment: Top 15 *most frequently* occurring - sorry I didn't specify. Editing now.

Comment: this? `ggplot(bigrams_joined, aes(bigrams)) +  stat_count(geom="bar")`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - unfortunately that tries to plot every single value, rather than the top 10 or 15. I have about 35000 rows and i'm only interested in the top 10 or 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to `count()` your bigrams (from dplyr), and then you need to order them in your plot. For that these days, I prefer to use something like `fct_reorder()` from forcats.

```r
library(janeaustenr)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

data_frame(txt = prideprejudice) %>%
    unnest_tokens(bigram, txt, token = "ngrams", n = 2) %>%
    count(bigram, sort = TRUE) %>%
    top_n(15) %>%
    ggplot(aes(fct_reorder(bigram, n), n)) +
    geom_col() +
    coord_flip() +
    labs(x = NULL)
#> Selecting by n
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you again Julia, another perfect answer!

Answer (score 1):

You could something like this, dplyr's `top_n`  function to filter the top 15 bigrams + ggplot to plot them.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


bigrams_joined %>%
  top_n(15, bigrams) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(bigrams)) + 
  geom_bar() +  
  coord_flip()
```

or ordered:

```
bigrams_joined %>%
  group_by(bigrams) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  top_n(15, bigrams) %>% 
  mutate(bigrams = reorder(bigrams, n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(bigrams)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately it is returning the top 15 sorted in alphabetical order from Z to A. I'm not sure why that is the convention of top_n() but that's what it is doing in this case.

Comment: that is not the top_n function, but ggplot taking over.

Comment: Ahh I see - thank you for your help with this though